# How to organize comic book location information in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a comic book database project, and I need to be able to include the various locations within a particular comic issue. There are a couple issues I have to work with:

- Locations are more often than not inside other locations (the "Daily
  Bugle building" is on "The corner of 39th street and 2nd Avenue" is
  in "New York City" is in "New York", etc.)
- While the hierarchy of locations is pretty standard
  (Universe->Dimension->Galaxy->System->Planet->Continent->Country->State->City->Street->Building->Room),
  not all the parent locations are necessarily known for every location
  (a comic might involve a named building in an unnamed country in
  Africa for instance).
- There are a few locations that don't fit into that nice hierarchy but
  branch off at some point (for instance, "The Savage Land" is a giant
  jungle in Antarctica, so while its parent is a Continent, it is not a
  country).

My main goal is to be able to run a search for any location and get all issues that have that location or any locations within that location. A secondary goal is to be able on the administration side of the application to be able to autocomplete full locations (ie I type in a new building for an issue and specify that it is in New York City, and it pulls all "New York City" instances -- yes, there is more than one :P -- in the database and lets me chose the one in Earth-616 or the one in Earth-1610 or I can just add a new New York City under different parent locations). All that front-end stuff I can do and figure out when the time comes, I'm just unsure of the database setup at this point.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**

After a lot of brainstorming with a couple peers, I think I have come up with a solution that is a bit simpler than the nested model that has been suggested.

The location table would look like this:

- ID
- Name
- Type (enum list of the previously mentioned categories, including an
  'other' option)
- Uni_ID (ID of the parent universe, null if not applicable)
- Dim_ID (ID of the parent Dimension, null if not applicable)
- Gal_ID (ID of the parent Galaxy, null if not applicable)

...and so on through all the categories...

- Bui_ID (ID of the parent Building, null if not applicable)

So while there are a lot of fields, searching and autocomplete work really easily. All the parents of any given location are right there in the row, all the children of any location can be found with a single query, and as soon as a type is defined for a new location, autocomplete would work easily. At this point, I'm leaning towards this approach instead of the nested model, unless anyone can point out any problems with this setup that I haven't seen.

Comment: So in your example, the savage land's only parent would be antarctica, and antarctica would be found under earth and so on.  But even tho savage land is a jungle and not a country, it should still be returned under the search for antarctica.

Comment: Do temporal values matter? For example, World Trade Center vs WTC memorial. Location is the same, but time is different.

Comment: Those would be two different "buildings", or more precisely the second one would be one of those exceptions that would have the same parent as the "WTC Building" (the street if it happens to be named in the comics) but not itself be a building. When all is said and done I might add a field for related location ids to link things like that, but that's the easy part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hierarchical data, I always prefer using a nested set model to a parent->child (adjacency) model. Look [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for a good explanation and example queries. It's a more complicated data model, but it makes querying and searching the data much easier.

Comment: This also allows you to be more granular where necessary or less granular (like the Savage Land example).

Comment: That was a great article, thanks for it. From what I read though, it almost looks like I could implement the nested set model much more cleanly than the adjacency list model. What are your thoughts on that model?

Comment: Wow ... I'm sorry. Apparently I type faster than I think. The nested set model is the one you want, the adjacency list is the parent/child model. I'm editing my post to reflect that.

Comment: Note that the nested set model is non-relational--it is metadata-based.  This has its own limitations and challenges.  If you are going to use it, take a look at this paper (skip the math and just focus on the idea unless you are a math maven):http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3115

Comment: I also posted some thoughts on the nested set model in the thread here:  http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=13662&HighLight=1.  Note that I am not against the nested set model in general, but it's not always a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I really like what @King Isaac linked earlier about the nested set model.  The only arguments I have with what the link said is scalability.  If you're defining your lft and rgt boundaries, you have to know how many elements you have, or you have to set arbitrarily large numbers and just hope that you never reach it.  I don't know how big this database will be and how many entries you'll have, but it's good to implement a model that doesn't require re-indexing and the such.  Here's my modified version

```
create table #locations (id varchar(100),
                         name varchar(300),
                         descriptn varchar(500),
                         depthLevelId int)

create table #depthLevel(id int,
                         levelName varchar(300))

                     ***Id level structuring*** 

                            10--level 1
              100                               101-- level 2           
     1000            1001               1010             1011       --level 3
 10000   10001   10010   10011     10100    10101    10110    10111     --level 4
```

Essentially this makes for super simple queries. The important part is the child id is comprised of the parent id plus whatever random id you want to give it.  It doesn't even have to be sequential, just unique.  You want everything in the universe?

```
SELECT * 
FROM #locations
WHERE id like '10%'
```

You want something down the 4th level?

```
SELECT * 
FROM #locations 
WHERE id like '10000%'
```

The id's might get a little long when you get down so many levels but does that really matter when you're writing simple queries?  And since it's just a string you can have a very large amount of expandability without ever having to reindex.